# Webservice error, "Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine'

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I can't seem to find any similar topics online regarding this, so apologies for the apparently elementary question...

I foolishly added a crystal report to a test form within a test project inside of a production Visual Studio solution file. I did my tests, and **deleted the crystal report from the project**.

Part of the solution is a webservice, which was working fine before I published a new version (since I added and removed the crystal report). Now it errors in the live environment:

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine'
```

There is no reference to crystal reports in the solution at all (that I can find).

References for the Webservice project (contained withing the global solution):
[image: WebServices References]

To keep the question size down I won't post the web.config file, but if you want it, let me know.

What on earth is going on? and why does my webservice require crystal reports on my webserver when it had absolutely nothing to do with this project!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i'd missed a few references to crystal reports in my main website project. Not that i'd have expected that to have affected my webservice (totally seperate project within the same solution), but it obviously did.

Mystery solved.

**edit:**

At the risk of sounding stupid, i feel its worth noting that my webservice is being hosted in a subdirectory within the IIS virtual directory that hosts the main site. IIS obviously loads the web.config file from the parent directory, during the load of any sub-sites/services. This was a new discovery for me.